# PHP break string into parts

Tags: php, explode

I have a string stored into $buffer which holds three informations

`tweetid category tweet`

eg.

```
123432 politics 'this is a political tweet'
```

I want to break it into parts such that 123432 is stored in one variable or array, politics into another array & this is a political tweet (without the quotes) into third array.

Additionally i want to read the third array word by word...

I tried using explode function  but the 'this is a political tweet' also got broken into parts...

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) also post code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continue to use the `explode()` function but specify the maximum number of explodes to perform.

[php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) description: *array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )*

```
explode(' ', $buffer, 3);
```

This should then give you

```
array(3) {
    [0]=>123432
    [1]=>politics
    [2]=>this is a political tweet
}
```

**Edit:**
If you need to remove the `'` from the beginning and the end of the tweet string then use the PHP trim functions.

```
rtrim(ltrim(array[2], "'"), "'");
```

Comment: What if the categorgy has a space within it?

Comment: The example doesn't specify a space will be present.  If a space is going to be present then a different identifier will be needed instead of a space...

Comment: Exactly why I posted my answer that immediately got voted down. My answer could be useful to a beginner so why vote it down?

Comment: some more code has to be written just to remove the single quotes from the 3rd index string as the question says the 3rd string should not contain single quotes

Comment: @karmafunk I haven't voted on your post.  However from the OPs question it would seem he doesn't have control over the tweet feed so adding a different identifier into the string isn't an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

`explode` accepts a `limit` number.

```
var_dump(explode(' ', "123432 politics 'this is a political tweet'", 3));
```

The result will be the following:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=> string(5) "23432"
    [1]=> string(8) "politics"
    [2]=> string(27) "'this is a political tweet'"
}
```